# FileHelpers - FieldOptional doesn't seem to work when using ReadStringAsDT

Tags: c#, xml, filehelpers

I'm using `DelimitedFieldBuilder` and marked my fields as `FieldOptional = true`.

I later create my class builder like so:

```
classBuilder = ClassBuilder.LoadFromXmlString(ColumnMappings);
```

I create my engine:

```
engine = new FileHelperEngine((classBuilder as DelimitedClassBuilder).CreateRecordClass());
```

I then populate the dataset like so:

```
var myString = "01,122242843,456183,160823,0716,84,80,1\n02,456183,122242843,1,160822,,USD,1/\n03,008066662,USD,010,0,,,015\n88,125,,450,1134403,,,570/";

using(var dt = engine.ReadStringAsDT(myString))
{
    using (var ds = new DataSet())
    {
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        var myXml = ds.GetXml());
    }
}
```

This seemed pretty straight forward. However the fields that lack values are still outputted by the `ds.GetXml()` call like so:

```xml
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <Credit>122242843/</Credit>
    <Field3>456183</Field3>
    <Field4>160823</Field4>
    <Field5>0716</Field5>
    <Field6>84</Field6>
    <Field7>80</Field7>
    <Field8>1</Field8>
    <Field9 />
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Notice `Field9`. It is marked using `FieldOptional = true`. I was under the impression that by marking it as optional, if there was no value, the Field element would not be output in the final XML. Is that not the case or am I missing another property setting perhaps?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards everyone!

Comment: The dataset/datatable will still get output with an empty value.

Comment: the output is always an empty value, regardless of whether or not I set the FieldOptional flag to True or False.

Comment: ok...I think I have this working.  I think I was running into some caching issues on my side, so it wasn't reflecting the change.  Thanks!